# Acceder a metodos de objetos contenidos en un stackpanel.Children

Tags: c#

Supongamos que meto en un `StackPanel` 5 objetos de la clase `ConfigNivel`, me gustaría después acceder a los métodos de estos 5 objetos, por ejemplo, al metodo `GetTotal()`, que se encuentran alojados en su interior `ConfigNivel().GetTotal()`

```
     private void ConstruirFilas(int numFilas)
     {

        for (int i = 1; i < numFilas; i++)
        {
            StackConfiguracion.Children.Add(new ConfigNivel(i));              
        }
     }
```

¿De que manera puedo acceder a estos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que los elementos `ConfigNivel` puedan alojarse en un StackPanel (que deriven de UIElement) para acceder a ellos se me ocurre que podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i = 0; i < StackConfiguration.Children.Count; i++)
{
    total += (StackConfiguracion.Children[i] as ConfigNivel).GetTotal();              
}
```

Esto funciona siempre que la clase `ConfigNivel`sea nulable. Si no, debes hacerlo así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < StackConfiguration.Children.Count; i++)
{
    total += ((ConfigNivel)StackConfiguracion.Children[i]).GetTotal();              
}
```

`total`sería una variable del mismo tipo que devuelva el método `GetTotal()`, que he usado como ejemplo, pero podrías acceder de esta manera a propiedades y métodos del objeto `ConfigNivel` correspondiente.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, lo pruebo esta tarde y te comento, y gracias una segunda vez pues creía que entre el primer fragmento de código y el segundo no había ninguna diferencia, creía que eran dos maneras de "parsear" de un tipo a otro sin tener en cuenta que la clase sea o no nullable... ¿Es así?

Comment: Cuando parseas un objeto así `DateTime x = miobjeto as DateTime`, si _miobjeto_ no es un **DateTime**, devuelve _null_. Si lo haces de esta otra manera `DateTime x = (DateTime)miobjeto` te genera una excepción (si _miobjeto_ no es un **DateTime**) y si no la controlas te detiene el código. El caso es que si el objeto que quieres obtener no es nullable (por ejemplo un **int**), no puedes usar el primer método. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Y seria posible acceder a un objeto de un StackPanel que a su vez esta contenido dentro de otro contenedor?
Es decir, ¿Seria algo asi como apuntar al indice dentro de otro indice?
No se si seria posible lo que comento... 
Me gustaria tener unos menus dinamicos los cuales tienen opciones que se forman dependiendo de "x" situaciones.
Gracias

Comment: Supongo que si. Sería algo del estilo a `((panel1.Children[0] as StackPanel).Children[x] as ConfigNivel).GetTotal()` siguiendo con el ejemplo de la pregunta. Se trata de ir encadenando.